# error : reserved word 'var' javascript

Tags: javascript

I have Gruntfile.js files. On the first line of JavaScript I get an error:

`error : reserved word 'var' JavaScript.`

Below is the line in the JavaScript file...

```
var coffeeFiles = [
'javascripts/hub_client/augury.js.coffee',
'javascripts/hub_client/common/**/*.coffee',
'javascripts/hub_client/extensions/**/*.coffee',
'javascripts/hub_client/mixins/*.coffee',
'javascripts/hub_client/events/**/*.coffee',
'javascripts/hub_client/models/**/*.coffee',
'javascripts/hub_client/collections/**/*.coffee',
'javascripts/hub_client/routers/**/*.coffee',
'javascripts/hub_client/templates/**/*.coffee',
'javascripts/hub_client/views/**/*.coffee'
 ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no problem with this line. You should focus on the coffee files.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I'm noting that is obvious is that the line does not have an ending semi-colon.  Otherwise, I will need more information to troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: I believe you have enough rep to comment, and this seems like a comment, why you post it as answer?

Comment: Like the variable coffeeFiles, i have another var like this one, that have semi-colon.should i want to post the entire js file

Comment: More information should help.  Like Feyyaz suggested, the problems may be in your coffee files.  If this were the case, you can identify the problem child using the process of elimination or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

if you have used var keyword inside var variable you will get this kind of an error message.This is a one way how you will get this error message